# What is the Sith Emperor Vitiate's lightsaber form?

Tags: star-wars, video-games

I have seen that in the *KOTR Star Wars* game, Sith Emperor (Vitiate) uses a Lightsaber.

I've never played the game, but those who have, based on his actions, what light-saber form does Vitiate employ?

The Forms are as follows:

- Form I: **Shii-Cho** is basic moves
- Form II: **Makashi** is like fencing, using as little energy as possible and turning an opponent's strikes against him
- Form III: **Soresu** is all about defense
- Form IV: **Ataru** heavily makes use of acrobatics
- Form V: **Djem So/Shien** uses a lot of power attacks and kinetic energy
- Form VI: **Niman** is the diplomats form and has no strengths or weakness
- Form VII: **Juyo** is like a dervish of destruction

Comment: I think this would be better suited for gaming.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Based on his fights with the Hero, he doesn't have a form per se. He prefers direct Force attacks than specific lightsaber moves.

Answer (score 1):

Since his lightsaber honestly is redundant because of how strong he is in the force, if he was to have one, I'd give him form III, Soresu. I would say this is the most likely one so he can hold off his enemies if they're close so he could prepare for a force-based attack. But that's my opinion, I'd love to debate it with someone if this ever gets seen again.

Comment: Unfortunately this site isn't for debating as it's NOT a forum, but a Q&A site, question gets asked, said question gets answered canonically, no messing about. If you would like to discuss your opinions with other users I suggest you go to the [Star Wars subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/starwars)